# (Python) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-requests

I'm getting the error below when I'm parsing the xml from the URL in the code. I won't post the XML because it's huge. The link is in the code below.

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-77e5e1b79ccc> in <module>()
     11 
     12 for child in root.iter('Materia'):
---> 13     if not child.find('EmentaMateria').text is None:
     14             ementa = child.find('EmentaMateria').text
     15 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

MY CODE:

```
url = 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/senador/4988/autorias'
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True

tree = ElementTree.parse(response.raw)

root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.iter('Materia'):
    if child.find('EmentaMateria').text is not None:
            ementa = child.find('EmentaMateria').text

    for child_IdMateria in child.findall('IdentificacaoMateria'):
        anoMateria = child_IdMateria.find('AnoMateria').text
        materia = child_IdMateria.find('NumeroMateria').text
        siglaMateria = child_IdMateria.find('SiglaSubtipoMateria').text



    print('Ano = '+anoMateria+' | Numero Materia = '+materia+' | tipo = '+siglaMateria+' | '+ementa)
```

What I'm overlooking here?
Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of checking if `child.find('EmentaMateria').text` is not `None`, you should make sure that `child.find('EmentaMateria')` is not `None` first.

Also, you should store the returning value of `child.find('EmentaMateria')` to avoid calling it twice.

Lastly, you should assign `ementa` a default value if `child.find('EmentaMateria')` is `None`; otherwise your `print` function below will be referencing an un-initialized variable.

Change:

```
if child.find('EmentaMateria').text is not None:
    ementa = child.find('EmentaMateria').text
```

to:

```
node = child.find('EmentaMateria')
if node is not None:
    ementa = node.text
else:
    ementa = None
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in function `getattr` to do the same without a temporary variable:

```
ementa = getattr(child.find('EmentaMateria'), 'text', None)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I just removed the `.text` in the if clause and it worked perfectly. I tried to use the `getattr` but it didn't work. It stops in the middle of the result and show an error: `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently working on some scraping and faced the same issue. I used the `getattr` function and worked with me perfectly. I'm scraping multiple data points and some of them doesn't have values and gave me error not finding `.text`. But now the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the code to parse an xml file, open the xml file with a text editor and inspect the tags. In my case there were some rogue tags at the end. Once i removed those, the code worked as expected.